# Sylius add to cart via CartItemController gives 0,00 total

Tags: php, cart, sylius

We are currently developing an ERP-based webshop with Sylius. One of the features is that a customer can select multiple sizes and quantities and add them to their cart in one action.

Normally Sylius would work with a request-based `ItemResolver` for only one variant. We've tried to override the `CartItemController` so that we would be able to loop the request variables and add all the items to the cart.

We tried to use this code:

```
    try {
        // When we have multiple
        $reqSize      = $request->request->get('size');
        $reqQuantity  = $request->request->get('quantity');
        $reqProductID = $request->request->get('product_id');
        $reqColorID   = $request->request->get('variant_color_id');

        if (null !== $reqSize && null !== $reqQuantity && null !== $reqProductID && null !== $reqColorID && count($reqSize) === count($reqQuantity)) {
            $provider            = $this->get('sylius.cart_provider'); // Implements the CartProviderInterface.
            $currentCart         = $provider->getCart();
            $priceCalculator     = $this->get('sylius.price_calculator');
            $availabilityChecker = $this->get('sylius.availability_checker');

            $productRepo = $this->get('sylius.repository.product');
            $variantRepo = $this->get('sylius.repository.product_variant');
            $sizeRepo    = $this->get('jartazi.repository.sizegrid_size');
            $colorRepo   = $this->get('jartazi.repository.color');

            $product = $productRepo->find(intval($reqProductID));
            $color   = $colorRepo->find(intval($reqColorID));

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($reqSize); $i++) {
                $size     = $sizeRepo->find(intval($reqSize[$i]));
                $variant  = $variantRepo->findOneBy(['object' => $product, 'size' => $size, 'color' => $color]);
                $quantity = intval($reqQuantity[$i]);

                if (null === $variant) {
                    throw new ItemResolvingException('Selected item is out of stock.');
                }


                if (null !== $product && null !== $color && null !== $size && null !== $variant) {
                    // Make a cart item
                    $item = $this->get('sylius.factory.cart_item')->createNew();

                    $item->setSize($size);
                    $item->setVariant($variant);
                    $item->setQuantity($quantity);

                    $context = ['quantity' => $quantity];

                    if (null !== $customer = $cart->getCustomer()) {
                        $context['groups'] = $customer->getGroups()->toArray();
                    }

                    $item->setUnitPrice($priceCalculator->calculate($variant, $context));

                    // Check for equal products
                    foreach ($currentCart->getItems() as $cartItem) {
                        if ($cartItem->equals($item)) {
                            $quantity += $cartItem->getQuantity();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!$availabilityChecker->isStockSufficient($variant, $quantity)) {
                        throw new ItemResolvingException('Selected item is out of stock.');
                    }

                    $event = new CartItemEvent($cart, $item);

                    // Update models
                    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SyliusCartEvents::ITEM_ADD_INITIALIZE, $event);
                    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SyliusCartEvents::CART_CHANGE, new GenericEvent($cart));
                    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SyliusCartEvents::CART_SAVE_INITIALIZE, $event);

                    // Write flash message
                    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SyliusCartEvents::ITEM_ADD_COMPLETED, new FlashEvent());
                }
            }

            return $this->redirectAfterAdd($configuration);
        }
    } catch (ItemResolvingException $exception) {
        // Write flash message
        $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SyliusCartEvents::ITEM_ADD_ERROR, new FlashEvent($exception->getMessage()));

        return $this->redirectAfterAdd($configuration);
    }
```

But when we add one to the cart, the cart total stays `0,00`

Are we missing something in order to have the correct totals when adding a CartItem without an ItemResolver?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified by Coudenysj you probably need to call the OrderItemQuantityModifier somewhere in your code.

I think you need to manually call the modifier before you set the quantity

```
$this->get('sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier')->modify($item, $quantity);

// $item->setQuantity($quantity);
```

Actually it appears you just need to call the modify function and it updates the quantity to the correct value

I had a lot of trouble making my own add to cart code for this reason. I ended up modifying the CartItemType. But now i do need to be able to add multiple to the cart at once. So i would be very interested to hear if this solves your issues.

Please post an update

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with use of this service we were able to correctly modify the quantity and the unit prices. Thanks, we clearly overlooked this service. Our modification of the CartItem (`$item->setQuantity($quantity);`) we also deleted as this was a custom method, the setter was normally not available.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier` service: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusOrderBundle/services.html#orderitemquantitymodifier.

Comment: The `OrderItem` gets created and added to the `Cart` but the units_total and the total remains `0`. Other stuff gets set like the unit_price and the quantity.